# Convert Repeating Decimals to Fraction

Tags: arithmetic

If there is a number $x = 0.333333333$ where 3 is repeated infinitely how to convert it to fraction ?
It is said that $-> 0.(3) = \frac{3}{10} - 1$ and $0.33 = \frac{33}{100} - 1$, But  I can't understand Why ?
I searched for similar Questions like this and i found answers but i didn't understand the prove.

Comment: Note that $3/10-1=0.3-1=-.7$.  You need parentheses because division takes precedence over subtraction

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $$x=0.\overline3\tag1$$
Then, $$10x=3.\overline3\tag2$$

Performing the subtraction $(2)-(1)$ yields
\begin{align}
10x-x&=3.\overline3-0.\overline3\\
9x&=3\\
x&=\frac13
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

If $$x = 0.33333333....$$ , then $$10x = 3.33333333....$$

Subtracting :  $10x - x = 3$  , The reason being that since the decimal is repeated till infinity , removing one term would not change it.  [Think about it!]

Evaluating : $$9x = 3$$
$$x = \frac{1}{3}$$